# How to make \adjustbox not scale down equation unless needed?

Tags: scaling, adjustbox

I do not know why `\adjustbox` seems to scale down an equation, when there is no need to do that, as the equation can fit in the text without scaling.

My understanding is that using `\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}` will *only* make it scale down/resize, if the current size is too large to fit. This is from the [manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox/adjustbox.pdf)

[image]

So I do not know what Am I doing wrong here.   As it is making the equation smaller compared to when not using `\adjustbox`.

I want `\adjustbox` to scale the equation only if it is too wide to fit into the `textwidth`. How to do that?

MWE. ps the actual equations are autogenerated. I just add the adjustbox around them

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mleftright}  
\mleftright

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{%
    $y \left(x \right) = \frac{\left(-4 x c_{2}+2 c_{1}\right) \sin \left(2 x \right)-4 \left(c_{1} x +\frac{c_{2}}{2}\right) \cos \left(2 x \right)}{\cos \left(2 x \right) c_{1}+\sin \left(2 x \right) c_{2}}$}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\adjustbox{max width=\pagewidth}{%
    $y \left(x \right) = \frac{\left(-4 x c_{2}+2 c_{1}\right) \sin \left(2 x \right)-4 \left(c_{1} x +\frac{c_{2}}{2}\right) \cos \left(2 x \right)}{\cos \left(2 x \right) c_{1}+\sin \left(2 x \right) c_{2}}$}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\adjustbox{max size={\pagewidth}{\pageheight}}{%
    $y \left(x \right) = \frac{\left(-4 x c_{2}+2 c_{1}\right) \sin \left(2 x \right)-4 \left(c_{1} x +\frac{c_{2}}{2}\right) \cos \left(2 x \right)}{\cos \left(2 x \right) c_{1}+\sin \left(2 x \right) c_{2}}$}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
y \left(x \right) = \frac{\left(-4 x c_{2}+2 c_{1}\right) \sin \left(2 x \right)-4 \left(c_{1} x +\frac{c_{2}}{2}\right) \cos \left(2 x \right)}{\cos \left(2 x \right) c_{1}+\sin \left(2 x \right) c_{2}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I tried few things above. Here is the output, compiled using `lualatex`

[image]

TL 2020 after OCT update. On Linux.

Comment: It doesn't scale, the y has the same size. But you no longer have a display math frac but inline/textstyle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the output of

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
a=\frac{b}{c}
\]
\[
\mbox{$a=\frac{b}{c}$}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

What's the difference? Of course that inside `\[...\]` (or `equation`, `equation*` and all other math displays) TeX starts in *display math mode*. To the contrary, inside `$...$` TeX starts in *inline math mode*.

If you want to strain your readers' eyes with that approach, at least do yourself the favor of defining a suitable shorthand:

```
\newcommand{\strain}[1]{\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{$\displaystyle#1$}}
```

With `\displaystyle` you get back to the display math mode in force at the beginning of the display.

Note that `\pagewidth` makes little sense, so I used `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mleftright}  
\mleftright

\newcommand{\strain}[1]{\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{$\displaystyle#1$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
y \left(x \right) = \frac{\left(-4 x c_{2}+2 c_{1}\right) 
\sin \left(2 x \right)-4 \left(c_{1} x +\frac{c_{2}}{2}\right) 
\cos \left(2 x \right)}{\cos \left(2 x \right) c_{1}+\sin \left(2 x \right) c_{2}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\strain{
    y \left(x \right) = \frac{\left(-4 x c_{2}+2 c_{1}\right) 
   \sin \left(2 x \right)-4 \left(c_{1} x +\frac{c_{2}}{2}\right) 
   \cos \left(2 x \right)}{\cos \left(2 x \right) c_{1}+\sin \left(2 x \right) c_{2}}
}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\strain{
    y \left(x \right) =
   \frac{\left(-4 x c_{2}+2 c_{1}\right) 
   \sin \left(2 x \right)-4 \left(c_{1} x +\frac{c_{2}}{2}\right) 
   \cos \left(2 x \right)}{\cos \left(2 x \right) c_{1}+\sin \left(2 x \right) c_{2}}
   \frac{\left(-4 x c_{2}+2 c_{1}\right) 
   \sin \left(2 x \right)-4 \left(c_{1} x +\frac{c_{2}}{2}\right) 
   \cos \left(2 x \right)}{\cos \left(2 x \right) c_{1}+\sin \left(2 x \right) c_{2}}
   \frac{\left(-4 x c_{2}+2 c_{1}\right) 
   \sin \left(2 x \right)-4 \left(c_{1} x +\frac{c_{2}}{2}\right) 
   \cos \left(2 x \right)}{\cos \left(2 x \right) c_{1}+\sin \left(2 x \right) c_{2}}
}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the fix. I know the difference between inline vs. display. But because I had both initially inside equation, I thought they will remain as display mode. I just did not realize that adding $$ inside equation makes it go back to inline mode.